# I want to open a new tab using the url which i have store into Table inside database in cakePhp wirth Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I want to open a new tab with the URL which I stored into a ProductTable inside a SQL database. For URL it has the field called web_url. Which i want fetch from it and open a new tab using Ajax request.

So, I have create form and then i store the input value and do a query using that input value then if it matching then send the web_url to the response to the ajax request to open into a new tab with it.

Here is code:- Basic html code

```
<div class="search-box">
      <form id = "searchForm" >
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search for products, brands..." aria-label="search-input" id="autocomplete" name="product-name">
        <input type="hidden" name="productID" id="productID">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id = "submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, when i click on submit button it store a value into productID variable then search a query matches the productID variable then gives the response URL to redirect or open into new tab. here is the JavaScript Code with the Ajax request:-

```
$('#submit-btn').on("click", function (event) {
  // Prevent the default action of the 'click' event, which is submitting the form
  event.preventDefault();

  //To get the search query from the input field
  var productID = $('#autocomplete').val();

  // Send an AJAX request to the searchProduct action in ProductsController
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      serviceUrl: '/products/searchProduct',
      data: { query: productID },
      dataType: 'json',
      ajaxSettings: {
        contentType: "application/json",
        accept: "application/json"
      },
      success: function (response) {
          // Check if there's an error in the response
          console.log(productID);
          if (response.error) {
              console.log(response.error);
          } else {
              // Redirect to the URL of the matching product
              // window.open('https://www.youtube.com', '_blank');
              console.log(response.url);
              window.open(response.url, '_blank');
          }
      },
      error: function (error) {
          // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message
          console.error('Error:', error);
      }
  });
});
```

Now here is ProductsController Code which I am using for the query to get that web_url-

```
public function searchProduct()
{
    $query = $this->request->getQuery('query');
    $product = $this->Products->find()->where(['name LIKE' => '%' . $query . '%'])-> first();

    // 'web_url' is a field in your Products table
    $url = $product ? $product->web_url : null;

    // Prepare the response data
    $response = [
        'error' => false,
        'url'   => $url,
    ];

    // Set the response as JSON
    $this->response = $this->response->withType("application/json")->withStringBody(json_encode($response));

    return $this->response;

}
```

It open a blank page but I want to open that URL which is store in web_url field into the productTable in the Database.

Comment: I have store url in the $response variable inside the function called searchProduct in the ProductsController which i have mention in above code.

Comment: tell us the value of `console.log(response.url);`

Comment: The value of "console.log(response.url)" is  "undefined".

Comment: exactly. Check your php code that why it is not returning `url` correctly.

Comment: Php code gives this  json response :- "{"error":false,"url":"https:\/\/www.fabindia.com\/natural-fabric-woven-tapered-drum-lampshade-10497603?currencyCode=INR&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpompBhDZARIsAFD_Fp-n7bAhVJz4cCarnlOvat5aOZ38PDqXu91bW9TMylMzjTgBhSj5jhkaAhCPEALw_wcB"}"

Comment: What does `console.log(response);` tell you?

Comment: Shouldnt this be `serviceUrl: '/products/search-product'` as dashed URL?

Comment: Read: https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/development/rest.html (cakephp 5), https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/rest.html (cake 4), or https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/rest.html cake 3